# Filter attributes in a list of dictionaries

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have two attributes I want to see from a list of dictionaries: `name` and `version`.

Expected output:

```yaml
name : kernel
vesion: 3.10.0
```

Input from a `yum` task:

```json
{
    "yumoutput": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "results": [{
                "arch": "x86_64",
                "envra": "0:kernel-3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64",
                "epoch": "0",
                "name": "kernel",
                "release": "1160.80.1.el7",
                "repo": "rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms",
                "version": "3.10.0",
                "yumstate": "available"
            },
            {
                "arch": "x86_64",
                "envra": "0:python-perf-3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64",
                "epoch": "0",
                "name": "python-perf",
                "release": "1160.80.1.el7",
                "repo": "rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms",
                "version": "3.10.0",
                "yumstate": "available"
            },
            {
                "arch": "noarch",
                "envra": "0:tzdata-2022f-1.el7.noarch",
                "epoch": "0",
                "name": "tzdata",
                "release": "1.el7",
                "repo": "rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms",
                "version": "2022f",
                "yumstate": "available"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My tasks:

```yaml
- name: List Available Patches (Non-Kernel)
  yum:
    list: updates
    update_cache: true
    exclude: kernel*
    security: true
  register: yumoutput

- name: Show result
  debug:
    var: yumoutput
```

How can I filter the output to keep only entries with `name: kernel` and `version: 3.10.0`?

Comment: I have cleaned your input @WhoAmI. Please mind that Ansible is outputting you JSON (in the callback you are using). So if you are unsure of what you provide in your question, take the extra step, and use a JSON linter: https://jsonlint.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to filter a dictionary you can:

1. convert it to list with [`dict2items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-dictionaries-into-lists)
2. only select the keys you care about with [`selectattr`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr)
3. and finally convert it back to a dictionary with [`items2dict`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-lists-into-dictionaries)

Since you have a list of dictionaries, you need to throw all those filters in [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map)'s.

So, given the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: >-
      yumoutput.results
        | map('dict2items')
        | map('selectattr', 'key', 'in', ['name', 'version'])
        | map('items2dict')
```

You get the expected:

```yaml
- name: kernel
  version: 3.10.0
- name: python-perf
  version: 3.10.0
- name: tzdata
  version: 2022f
```

Comment: [2022-11-24T15:35:09.601Z] TASK [security_patching : debug] ***********************************************

[2022-11-24T15:35:09.601Z] Thursday 24 November 2022  15:35:09 +0000 (0:00:03.113)       0:00:17.738 ***** 

[2022-11-24T15:35:09.601Z] Thursday 24 November 2022  15:35:09 +0000 (0:00:03.113)       0:00:17.737 ***** 

 ok: [40.118.86.58 -> 172.16.5.4] => {
 "yumoutput.results\n  | map('dict2items')\n  | map('selectattr', 'key', 'in', ['name', 'version'])\n  | map('items2dict')": []

That is what I get from the output

Comment: @WhoAmI I edited the answer to make it work in most situations and ansible versions.

Comment: Sadly I get an empty result :(

Comment: Sadly, you are not running that task against the same result you have in your example.

Comment: @Zeitounator I am curious about your edit, how would `msg` work on a broader range of Ansible version than `var`?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε missread the "error" (actually not one) reported in OP's comment above. Meanwhile I'm never confortable with `var:` option containing pipes and filters (although it is valid....)

Comment: @Zeitounator, I guess as everyone, I started only using `msg` and so, templating those messages, mostly because I didn’t know about `var` in debug. Now that I use it, I quite like to use it extensively, it kind of help me remember that some modules or options are always templated (like some fields in the dynamic inventories or in `when`). So, it’s like a mental gymnastics to keep reminding me of those.

Answer (score 1):

As a follow-up to @β.εηοιτ.βε's answer, if you have a recent enough install of ansible with the [`ansible.utils` collection](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/index.html) available, you can acheive the same result using the [`ansible.utils.keep_keys` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/keep_keys_filter.html#ansible-collections-ansible-utils-keep-keys-filter)

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ yumoutput.results
         | ansible.utils.keep_keys(target=['name', 'version']) }}"
```

Gives:

```
TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "name": "kernel",
            "version": "3.10.0"
        },
        {
            "name": "python-perf",
            "version": "3.10.0"
        },
        {
            "name": "tzdata",
            "version": "2022f"
        }
    ]
}
```